# How to combine AuthedRoutes and HttpRoutes in http4s?

Tags: scala, http4s

Is there any rule how http4s prioritize `AuthedRoutes` over `HttpRoutes` when both of them are combined with `<+>`

Because I receive 401 for such a combination `authRoute <+> route`, when calling:

```
GET /non-authed-route
```

The behavior changes, and I receive 200 for the same request, when I reorder the routes `route <+> authRoute`.

It may be even more messy when you need to work with 5+ routes which you need to combine and some of them may contain regular and secured endpoints simultaneously.

Answer (score 9):

So, though the question lacks some context information or code, I am going to assume that your problem is similar enough to a common one:

First, I assume your code has this approximate form, and is built with an `AuthedRoutes.of` (defined [here](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/http4s/AuthedRoutes.scala#L31-L35)), and an `AuthMiddleware`:

```
    val moonAuthedRoutes: AuthedRoutes[F, Int] = AuthedRoutes.of {
      case GET -> / sky / moon as T(42)
    }
    val marsRoutes: HttpRoutes[F] = HttpRoutes.of {
      case GET -> / sky / mars
    }
    // assuming you have your authedMiddleware 
    val moonRoutes = authedMiddleware(moonAuthedRoutes)
    val composedRoutes = moonRoutes <+> marsRoutes
```

Now, it helps if you understand the types of the aliases involved, and what they come down to once you unwrap `Kleisli` and `OptionT`:

```scala
type HttpRoutes[F, T] 
  = Kleisli[OptionT[F, ?], Request[F, T], Response[F]]
  ~~ Request[F] => F[Option[Response[F]]

type AuthedRoutes[F, T] 
  = Kleisli[OptionT[F, ?], AuthedRequest[F, T], Response[F]]
  ~~ (T, Request[F]) => F[Option[Response[F]]
```

In essence, a function that takes the HTTP request and some authentication context, and may give compute some response or none (inside a computation in `F`). To transform this `AuthedRoutes` into an `HttpRoutes`, you use an authentication *middleware*: a wrapper on your `AuthedRoutes` that takes  the Request, tries to extract the `T` from it, if it succeeds it wraps the request with that `T` and passes it to the `AuthedRoutes`, as done [in this line of code](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/master/server/src/main/scala/org/http4s/server/middleware/authentication/package.scala#L17). If the middleware can not authenticate the request (that is extract the `T`), as [of this line](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/master/server/src/main/scala/org/http4s/server/middleware/authentication/package.scala#L16), it short-circuits and returns a **401 Unauthenticated** response.

Now, the `<+>` composition first applies to the request on the `moonRoutes`. If the result of that is *some* response, that is what the composed routes returns. *Only if* the `moonRoutes` routes (at the left of `<+>`) return an `F(None)` will the composition pass the request on to `marsRoutes`. In particular, when you give it an unauthenticated request, the `moonRoutes` returns *some* **401 Unauthenticated** response, and that is what the `composedRoutes` return, without ever passing the request on to `marsRoutes`.

If you swap the order, though, and write `composedRoutes = marsRoutes <+? moonRoutes`, then unauthenticated requests to the unauthenticated endpoints are answered in `marsRoutes`; whereas authenticated requests are first tried in `marsRoutes`, which fails (gives an `F(None)`), and then passed on to `moonRoutes`, which succeeds.

Comment: What is the `~~` operator?

Comment: @PeterLamberg Oh, that is not an operator. That is just my pseudo-notation for "it comes down to", or similar, for deciphering the `Kleisli` and `OptionT` into a more readable type.